My supabase function definition always raise 'not found' exception
I'm trying to make a function to check whether or not the user-specified password matches their password. But it always raise an exception.
exception: not found <NULL>
I need you guys to help me fix this issue so that this function works properly and tell me which part I did it wrong.
Here is the code
drop function if exists "public"."check_password"(email text, passwd text);

set check_function_bodies = off;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.check_password(passwd text)
 RETURNS boolean
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$declare
_uid uuid; -- for checking by 'is not found'
begin
if (passwd = '') then
  raise exception 'Password cannot be empty';
end if;

select id into _uid
from auth.users
where id = auth.uid()
and encrypted_password = crypt(passwd::text, auth.users.encrypted_password);

if not found then
  raise exception 'not found %', _uid;
end if;

return true;
end;$function$
;

EDIT
I tried the script on the SQL Editor, somehow it works..
select id
from auth.users
where id = '3829daea-4144-4d1a-9642-234ba35d7d2b'
and encrypted_password = crypt('password', auth.users.encrypted_password);




id




3829daea-4144-4d1a-9642-234ba35d7d2b




I'm trying to make a function to check whether or not the user-specified password matches , your function you want to check is check_password"(email text, passwd text) but you are processing with one parameter check_password"(passwd text) , why??

Hi @nabinsademba .. That one was the previously created function. I made a mistake and I wrote a drop function to recreate it. There is drop function if exists in the begining

ok got your issue , change this
if not found then
  raise exception 'not found %', _uid;
end if;

to
if _uid is null then
  raise exception 'User not found or password does not match. User ID: %', _uid;
end if;

you are getting error because of how you handle the not found case, raising an exception with  '%', _uid when _uid is NULL could result in an unexpected exception message, like not found <NULL>

Hello nabin, thanks for answering. I tried to change it as you mentioned, it still raising the same exception. I think the problem is on the select statement instead. I also think that <NULL> was actually the query results. Please have a look https://imgur.com/a/AYWwSun

yes exactly its the query result , i have edited the  null case , so that you can confirm but your got the point.

Well, this is weird because the user exists...

my suggestion is you pass the id parameter explicitly to the function along with password, it will be more flexible

good idea, let me try that

Following nabin sademba's suggestion in the comment leads me to a working solution. I changed my code to this, and it finally works as expected.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.check_password(user_id text, passwd text)
 RETURNS boolean
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$declare
_uid uuid; -- for checking by 'is not found'
begin
if (user_id = '') or (passwd = '') then
  raise exception 'User id or password cannot be empty';
end if;

select id into _uid
from auth.users
where id = user_id::uuid
and encrypted_password = crypt(passwd::text, auth.users.encrypted_password);

if _uid is null then
  raise exception 'not found %', _uid;
end if;

return true;
end;$function$
;



You can radically improve and simplify to:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.check_password(user_id uuid, passwd text)
  RETURNS boolean
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF passwd = '' THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Password cannot be empty!';
   END if;

   IF EXISTS (
      SELECT FROM auth.users u
      WHERE  u.id = user_id
      AND    u.encrypted_password = crypt(passwd, u.encrypted_password)
      ) THEN
      RETURN true;
   ELSE
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'No entry found for the given user and password.';
   END IF;
END
$func$;


auth.users.id must be defined NOT NULL. Then this is a faster equivalent.

Make the function take uuid right away, instead of passing text and casting later. Also catches an empty string as invalid UUID right away.

You don't go on using auth.users.id for anything. So don't bother to store it in a variable. EXISTS is simpler and faster. See:

PL/pgSQL checking if a row exists


It's not useful to report null when no entry was found.

It's good style to table-qualify all columns with a short table alias - as opposed to using the fully qualified table name for one column and not others.


